# Angular JS - Cannot push object into scope array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im sure im missing something probably very basic but cant seem to wrap my head around this issue. I am simple trying to push an object into a scope array on click. I am currently getting error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)`

Heres an example of what I got so far:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    

app.factory('MyService', function($http, $q, $timeout){

    var My_Stored_Data = {}

    return {

        template: function(){

            var template = { data1: "", data2: "", data3: "", data4: "" }
            return template

        }

    }              
});
```

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope,$q,MyService) {

    $scope.Main_scope = {};

    $scope.add_new_object = function(){

        $scope.Main_scope.My_array.push(MyService.template());
        //This give an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…) 
    }

});
```

Anyone have anyidea what im missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize My_array  inside the Main_scope Object

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope,$q,MyService) {
     $scope.Main_scope = {};
     $scope.Main_scope.My_array =[];
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is verbose and clear `My_array` is not defined.

You need to define the array in your `Main_scope` variable.

```
$scope.Main_scope = {
    My_array : []
};
```